# How to download the content of the page despite the Error 500?

Tags: java, http-status-code-500

I want to download the content of the page:
https://www.hafen-hamburg.de/en/vessels/klein-erna/. In my code and DevTools I can see that I'm getting a 500 error:

[image: Statuscode 500]

but I can also clearly see in the browser that the page has been loaded. How can I download the content of the page despite this error?

My code:

```
    String pageUrl = "https://www.hafen-hamburg.de/en/vessels/klein-erna/";
    URL url = new URL(pageUrl);
    String content = IOUtils.toString(url, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: The Apache `commons-io` library you are using is pretty primitive. I would try a different library like [HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.2.x/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for your comment (@egeorge) I used the [HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.2.x/index.html) library and got exactly what I wanted.

Code:

```
    String pageUrl = "https://www.hafen-hamburg.de/en/vessels/klein-erna/";
    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create(pageUrl)).build();
    HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    System.out.println(response.body());
```